# Данные в React из JSON

Tags: json, reactjs

```
const API = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceRHciXcVu?indent=2';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           hits: []
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch(API)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({ hits: data.hits }));
    }

    render() {
        const { hits } = this.state;
        console.log(this.state.hits);
        return (
          <div>
            {hits.map(hit =>
              <div key={hit._id}>
                <span>{hit.company}</span>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Вот с таким кодом получаю ошибку
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
и в консоли тоже undefined.

Второй день бьюсь, буду признателен за советы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас из фетча приходит массив объектов, а не объект.

```
.then(data => this.setState({ hits: data }));
```

Comment: спасибо, работает)

Comment: Если ответ решил вашу проблему, вы можете отметить его соответствующие.

Comment: я бы с радостью, но не хватает репутации :(  Как только достигну - обязательно проголосую.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала я бы разобрался с получением данных из API. Вы используете `fetch` при вызове которого возвращается `Promise`. Соответственно, если вы не видите данных в рендере, то данные возможно и не пришли. Перепишите ваш метод следующим образом:

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => { 
          console.log('data', data); // обратите внимание на этот вывод
          this.setState({ hits: data.hits });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error)); // этот выполнится в случае ошибки
}
```

И посмотрите в консоль, что у вас произошло. Может упала ошибка или же данные не пришли. А может когда вы в `state` проставляете `hits` выбираете все же не то, что вам нужно, в общем, посмотрите внимательно, что вы получаете от API.

Если ради примера переписать ваш пример вот так:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hits: [] };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      hits: [{
        _id: 1,
        company: 'A'
      }, {
        _id: 2,
        company: 'B'
      }, {
        _id: 3,
        company: 'C'
      }]
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { hits } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.hits);
    return (
      <div>
        {hits.map(hit =>
          <div key={hit._id}>
            <span>{hit.company}</span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

то на экране отобразится три блока с надписью "*A B C*". Поэтому дело именно в вашем API и обработке полученных данных.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Как написали выше - я получал массив объектов, а не один объект. А я пытался его обработать, как объект. Почему-то во всех учебных примерах показан именно объект на входе, и я не мог понять, в чём у меня ошибка.